# Assembly 8086 - Get time without using interrupts from DOS

Tags: assembly, time, x86-16, emu8086

How can I get the time without using interrupts from DOS?

Comment: Maybe [read the RTC](https://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS#Getting_Current_Date_and_Time_from_RTC)

Comment: If the ROM-BIOS handler or a compatible handler is still installed and called, and the IRQ #0 timer of the PIT is still set up as usual, then the `dword [40h:6Ch]` will hold the ticks into the day. This counts from 0 to 18_00AFh from midnight starting a day to just before midnight ending a day. That's almost exactly 64 kilo-binary ticks per hour, and about 18.2 ticks per second. (You can divide by 65536 to get an approximate hour of the day.)

Answer (score 2):

> get the time without using interrupts from DOS

If you don't want to use the DOS.GetSystemTime function 2Ch (`int 21h`), there's always the BIOS.GetRealTimeClockTime function 02h (`int 1Ah`). Both these functions return hours in CH, minutes in CL, and seconds in DH **but** unlike DOS that returns integers, BIOS returns the numbers in the BCD format.

```
23:17:45     DOS     vs     BIOS
         --------------------------
         CH=23 (17h)    CH=35 (23h)
         CL=17 (11h)    CH=23 (17h)
         DH=45 (2Dh)    CH=69 (45h)
```

---

### Clock displaying hh:mm

If you don't want to use either of the above mentioned functions, then a close-enough approximation comes from reading the BIOS.TimerTick held at memory address 046Ch (dword).
Due to the simplified math, the first minute of the day (and only the first minute) will take around 70 sec. If your program doesn't display seconds, the user won't even notice this.

```
; -> CH is hours [0,23]
; -> CL is minutes [0,59]
; IN () OUT (cx,dx)
GetTimeHM:
  cli
  push ds
  push ax
  xor  cx, cx                     ; 00:00
  mov  ds, cx
  mov  al, byte ptr [046Ch + 2]   ; [0,24]
  cmp  al, 24
  je   .OK
  mov  ch, al                     ; Hours [0,23]
  mov  ax, 60
  mul  word ptr [046Ch]
  mov  cl, dl                     ; Minutes [0,59]
.OK:
  xor  dx, dx
  pop  ax
  pop  ds
  sti
  ret
```

For verification, I wrote next program that displays the current time in *hh:mm* format on the console:

```
  ORG  256                    ; Creating a .COM program

  mov  bh, -1                 ; LastKnownMinutes
Main:
  call GetTime                ; -> CH CL DH=0 DL=0
  cmp  cl, bh
  je   Main                   ; Minutes didn't change
  mov  bh, cl
  mov  bl, ':'
  mov  al, ch                 ; Hours
  call PrintTrio              ; -> (AX DX)
  mov  bl, 13
  mov  al, cl                 ; Minutes
  call PrintTrio              ; -> (AX DX)
  mov  dl, 10
  mov  ah, 02h                ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  mov  ah, 01h                ; BIOS.CheckKeystroke
  int  16h                    ; -> AX ZF
  jz   Main                   ; No key waiting
  mov  ah, 00h                ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
  int  16h                    ; -> AX
  ret                         ; TerminateProgram
; ----------------------------
; IN (al,bl) OUT () MOD (ax,dx)
PrintTrio:
  aam                         ; -> AH = AL / 10, AL = AL % 10
  add  ax, '00'               ; Convert to ASCII
  push ax                     ; (1)
  mov  dl, ah
  mov  ah, 02h                ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  pop  dx                     ; (1)
  mov  ah, 02h                ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  mov  dl, bl
  mov  ah, 02h                ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  ret
; ----------------------------
; -> CH is hours [0,23]
; -> CL is minutes [0,59]
; IN () OUT (cx,dx)
GetTimeHM:

  ...

  ret
; ----------------------------
```

### Clock displaying hh:mm:ss

The approximation from the above snippets can't deliver a good-enough value for the seconds.
Next code first converts the BIOS.TimerTick into BigSeconds [0,86399], and then those BigSeconds get distributed amongst the hours, minutes, and seconds of the clock. It uses an algorithm to divide a 32-bit number by another 32-bit number, something the architectural `div` instruction can't do [8086](/questions/tagged/8086). The remainder from this division is not used.

```
; -> CH is hours [0,23]
; -> CL is minutes [0,59]
; -> DH is seconds [0,59]
; IN () OUT (cx,dx)     ; BigSeconds = Ticks / 18.2065
GetTimeHMS:             ;            = (Ticks * 2000) / (18.2065 * 2000)
  push ds               ;            = (Ticks * 2000) / 36413
  push ax
  push bx
  push si

  xor  si, si
  mov  ds, si
  lds  bx, dword ptr [046Ch] ; BIOS.TimerTick
  mov  ax, ds                ; AX:BX [0,1573039]

  mov  cx, 2000              ; AX:BX * 2000
  mul  cx
  xchg bx, ax
  mul  cx
  add  dx, bx                ; DX:AX [0,3146078000] (Ticks * 2000)
  mov  bx, 36413             ; (18.2065 * 2000)

  mov  cx, 32                ; DX:AX / BX -> DX:AX [0,86399]
.again:
  shl  ax, 1                 ; SI:DX:AX << 1, Clears bit in quotient
  rcl  dx, 1
  rcl  si, 1
  jc   .on
  cmp  si, bx
  jb   .off
.on:
  inc  ax                    ; Sets bit in quotient
  sub  si, bx
.off:
  loop .again

  mov  bx, 3600              ; DX:AX is BigSeconds [0,86399]
  div  bx
  mov  ch, al                ; Hours [0,23]
  mov  al, 60
  xchg ax, dx
  div  dl
  mov  cl, al                ; Minutes [0,59]
  mov  dh, ah                ; Seconds [0,59]
  mov  dl, 0

  pop  si
  pop  bx
  pop  ax
  pop  ds
  ret
```

Again for verification, I wrote next program that displays the current time in *hh:mm:ss* format on the console:

```
  ORG  256                    ; Creating a .COM program

  mov  bh, -1                 ; LastKnownSeconds
Main:
  call GetTime                ; -> CH CL DH DL=0
  cmp  dh, bh
  je   Main                   ; Seconds didn't change
  mov  bh, dh
  mov  bl, ':'
  mov  al, ch                 ; Hours
  call PrintTrio              ; -> (AX DX)
  mov  al, cl                 ; Minutes
  call PrintTrio              ; -> (AX DX)
  mov  bl, 13
  mov  al, bh                 ; Seconds
  call PrintTrio              ; -> (AX DX)
  mov  dl, 10
  mov  ah, 02h                ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  mov  ah, 01h                ; BIOS.CheckKeystroke
  int  16h                    ; -> AX ZF
  jz   Main                   ; No key waiting
  mov  ah, 00h                ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
  int  16h                    ; -> AX
  ret                         ; TerminateProgram
; ----------------------------
; IN (al,bl) OUT () MOD (ax,dx)
PrintTrio:
  aam                         ; -> AH = AL / 10, AL = AL % 10
  add  ax, '00'               ; Convert to ASCII
  push ax                     ; (1)
  mov  dl, ah
  mov  ah, 02h                ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  pop  dx                     ; (1)
  mov  ah, 02h                ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  mov  dl, bl
  mov  ah, 02h                ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  ret
; ----------------------------
; -> CH is hours [0,23]
; -> CL is minutes [0,59]
; -> DH is seconds [0,59]
; IN () OUT (cx,dx)
GetTimeHMS:

  ...

  ret
; ----------------------------
```

Comment: I didn't believe that multiplying by 60 would work to extract the minutes (and by 60*60 to extract the seconds) but I ran your test program and it does work. (Not as accurate [as lClock's handling](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/lclock/file/f19bffe0230c/resident.asm#l240) but close enough.) I missed that you're using `dl` which is the low half of the upper 16 bits of the multiply result. I cannot quite explain it but I do understand now. 60 minutes to an hour means that if you use only the low word (truncate hours) and multiply it by 60 then the high word of the multiply result is minutes.

Comment: @ecm I know you didn't put your lClock up for review, but I think you will want to correct next issues: Your code supports a 'regular' and a *MORE_ACCURATE* time calculation through intricate use of conditional assembly. The *MORE_ACCURATE* version displays midnight as "24:00:00" which I find unusual, but which could be fine depending your locality. You can easily avoid it though, by changing *DIVISOR_HOURS_TIMES_1000* from 65543333 into 65543334.

Comment: @ecm The 'regular' version on the other hand is broken! "59" sec is followed by "60" sec before turning into "00" sec. The same is true for the minutes. And midnight shows "23:59:60" -> "23:60:00" -> "23:60:01" -> "24:00:00" for a total duration of 3.4 sec. There's no cure for this. The divisors 65543, 1092, and 18 cannot possibly produce an accurate result. I wonder, did you anticipate an use case for this 'regular' version?

Comment: The non-accurate version was IIRC created first, naively, and then problems exactly like what you suggest here were the reason I created the more accurate handling. The more accurate handling is also the default if you do not specify otherwise, with good reason. So, no, there is no use case or benefit to using the less accurate version (except slightly smaller memory use). Using the demo mode (/D switch) I see 23:59:59 and 00:00:00 for one tick before midnight (18_00B0h - 1 ticks) and exactly midnight respectively. For one more tick I do get 24:00:00 but I thought that never occurs.

Comment: @ecm If the non-accurate version is no longer needed, perhaps remove it then. It would improve readability a lot, omitting much of the conditional assembly. And it would better show opportunities to optimize the accurate version.

Comment: I might if I revisit the resident part at some point, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Here are three examples of int 8 handlers: https://gist.github.com/taylorza/d93d3aad9b4e5d86630ad264944c00ae#file-pcbios-asm-L5795 and https://github.com/dosemu2/dosemu2/blob/014d619acda9d4c4d66162b8d522744f998603cf/src/base/bios/x86/bios.s#L925 and https://github.com/640-KB/GLaBIOS/blob/0d215eb173f2802de3dd4ec66d2d9934e068e4dd/src/GLABIOS.ASM#L10488 All of those reset the tick count to 0 if it reaches 18_00B0h, so the int 1Ch handler sees 18_00AFh as the maximum tick count, which lClock displays as 23:59:59 correctly.

Comment: Busy looking into it...

Comment: Related question: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/why-did-some-bioses-have-the-timer-tick-wrap-around-at-1800b1h-instead-of-at-180